# Index out of bounds of the array vb.net

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting an error at this line:

```
        CheckedListBox3.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox3.CheckedItems(0))
```

I don't understand why because it does read the first two but not the third... the index of my checkedlistbox1, 2 and 3 is 3 so that makes it (0), (1), and (2) in each while...

Please help me out and tell me where i am wrong because i don't understand how it's possible that he can find the index of the first and second listbox but can't find the index of the third listbox

This is my code:

```
 cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT serienaam, ouderdom, aantal FROM klantserie Where klantnummer = '" & klantnummer & "' ", con)

        Dim ttr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        While ttr.Read = True

            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(ttr.Item("serienaam"))   "serienaam" = a-map or c-map
            CheckedListBox2.Items.Add(ttr.Item("ouderdom"))    "ouderdom" = week1 - week16
            CheckedListBox3.Items.Add(ttr.Item("aantal"))      "aantal" =  1 - 10

        End While
```

added the code that adds the items to the checkedlistbox

```
    Private Sub Button79_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button79.Click



    While CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1 >= 0     ''i have changed this line a few times don't really know if it matters to the outcome of the error''

        Dim serienaam
        Dim oud

        Dim aantal As Integer
        Dim bedrag As Decimal
        Dim totaal As Decimal

        Try
            serienaam = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0)
            oud = CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems(0)
            aantal = CheckedListBox3.CheckedItems(0)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & oud & " FROM series Where naamserie = '" & serienaam & "' ", con)

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If sdr.Read = True Then
            Dim week = sdr.Item(oud)
            bedrag = week * aantal
            totaal = Label69.Text
            totaal = totaal - bedrag

            sdr.Close()
            Label69.Text = totaal

        End If



        CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0))

        CheckedListBox2.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems(0))
        Try
            CheckedListBox3.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox3.CheckedItems(0))   ''<<<----error
        this try doesn't do anything actually except for the fact that im not getting any errors anymore 
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim s = CheckedListBox3.Items.Count
                CheckedListBox3.SelectedItem = s
                CheckedListBox3.Items.Remove(s)

            End If
        End Try



    End While

End Sub
```

this is the code for the check

```
    Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

    Dim index As Integer = e.Index

    CheckedListBox2.SetItemChecked(index, e.NewValue)
    CheckedListBox3.SetItemChecked(index, e.NewValue)

End Sub
```

my solution since it didn't work.

```
           Private Sub Button76_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button76.Click
    Dim serienaam
    Dim oud
    Dim aantal As Integer
    Dim bedrag As Decimal
    Dim totaal As Decimal
    Dim t As String

    serienaam = ComboBox6.SelectedItem
    oud = ComboBox7.SelectedItem
    aantal = TextBox45.Text




    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & oud & " FROM series Where naamserie = '" & serienaam & "' ", con)

    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If sdr.Read = True Then
        Dim week = sdr.Item(oud)
        bedrag = week
        totaal = Label69.Text
        totaal = totaal + bedrag * aantal



        sdr.Close()
        Label69.Text = totaal
        t = " '" & serienaam & "'                     '" & oud & "'                         '" & aantal & "' "
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(t)



    End If


End Sub

          Private Sub Button79_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button79.Click



    While CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0

        Dim klantnr As String
        Dim serienaam As String
        Dim oud As String
        Dim list As String
        Dim aantal As Integer
        Dim bedrag As Decimal
        Dim totaal As Decimal
        klantnr = TextBox32.Text

        list = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0)
        Dim strlist = list.Split("'")
        For count = 0 To strlist.Length - 1
            serienaam = strlist(1)
            oud = strlist(3)
            aantal = strlist(5)
        Next

        cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT " & oud & " FROM series Where naamserie = '" & serienaam & "' ", con)

        Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        If sdr.Read = True Then
            Dim week = sdr.Item(oud)
            bedrag = week * aantal
            totaal = Label69.Text
            totaal = totaal - bedrag

            sdr.Close()
            Label69.Text = totaal

        End If

        cmd = New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM klantserie Where klantnummer = '" & klantnr & "' And serienaam = '" & serienaam & "' And ouderdom = '" & oud & "' And aantal = '" & aantal & "' ", con)

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ShowData()

        CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0))

    End While

End Sub
```

Comment: Your while checks only if `CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0` but not the other `CheckedListBox`.

Comment: my bad shouldve said that the checkedlistboxitems are shared. so if checkedlistbox1 item(2) = checked than CheckedlistBox2 item(2) = also checked CheckedlistBox3 item(2) = also checked.

Comment: Are you sure that `SELECT serienaam, ouderdom, aantal FROM klantserie Where klantnummer = '" & klantnummer & "' "` is briging back the expected number of records for the field `aantl`?

Comment: yeah when i execute the program all checkedlistboxes are filled. and all the numbers of records are of the same amount

Comment: Debug lsitbox 3, and see if it indeed has any items in it... maybe your loading the item into listbox 3 does not happen, maybe an error is thrown when adding the tiem to listbox3, that you are not catching... Maybe the item is there, but not checked, as you expect it to be...

Comment: the problem comes at the point when i want to delete those items

Comment: example: button 1 fills the checkedlistbox . and button 2 deletes the items i selected. the items selected are Always in the same item selection. so if i select item (3) in listbox1 item 3 also gets selected in listbox 2 & 3

Comment: Not according to what you've written it doesn't: The problem occurs when you try to access the checked items in CheckedListBox3. I'm assuming that when you check on box you check all three, is that right? Have you checked to ensure that this logic is working as expected? CheckedItems is not being populated which suggests that the listbox is not seeing a check event happening.

Comment: ill try that maybe it is because i also applied an uncheck function which could cause checkbox3 to be unchecked because the items in listbox 1 & 2 are gone. thanks  i hope that's it

Comment: Chaining these things can be a right pain at times - hope you find the problem.

Comment: oke it doesn't look like that is the problem because the items are deleted at the end of the while loop.. so the items should still be shown at the beginning - it would make sence if the error was at the end.

Comment: okay i tried to delete the first item in the checkedlistbox and that worked. the checkedlistbox has 3 items. i can delete the first item the second item gives an error at the end of the while loop. makes sence to me so im gonna build another handler for this.but when i run again and at 3 items and try to delete the third the error comes at the beginning of the while loop... and that's weird

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've fixed this but I tried to reproduce the problem and failed. Here's what I used:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("List1Item1")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("List1Item2")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("List1Item3")

    CheckedListBox2.Items.Clear()
    CheckedListBox2.Items.Add("List2Item1")
    CheckedListBox2.Items.Add("List2Item2")
    CheckedListBox2.Items.Add("List2Item3")

    CheckedListBox3.Items.Clear()
    CheckedListBox3.Items.Add("List3Item1")
    CheckedListBox3.Items.Add("List3Item2")
    CheckedListBox3.Items.Add("List3Item3")

End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck

    Dim index As Integer = e.Index

    CheckedListBox2.SetItemChecked(index, e.NewValue)
    CheckedListBox3.SetItemChecked(index, e.NewValue)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    While CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0

        Dim serienaam As String
        Dim oud As String
        Dim aantal As String


        serienaam = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0)
        oud = CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems(0)
        aantal = CheckedListBox3.CheckedItems(0)

        CheckedListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(0))
        CheckedListBox2.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox2.CheckedItems(0))
        CheckedListBox3.Items.Remove(CheckedListBox3.CheckedItems(0))
    End While
End Sub
```

This works just fine. I can add items to the boxes using Button 1 and then check anything in the first box (which checks the corresponding items in the other boxes based on index - couldn't be bothered to wire up lists 2 and 3 to do the same) and then I can delete the checked items with no errors using Button2. The only change to yours is obviously I'm using mocked data, not SQL queries.

Comment: alright used some of ur data and it almost works the only problem is that when my checkedlistbox(1, 2 & 3) all have 3 values and i select the bottom 3 values i get an error : index out of bounds of the array. than if i use an exception handler and try to let it proceed the program doesn't only delete the bottom 3 values but also the second value of checkedlistbox(1 & 2(the value from checkedlistbox3 is not deleted))

Comment: I managed to check and delete any combination of the items, including if it was just the bottom three. Can you post complete code (substitute the SQL stuff with fixed values) including how you are setting the checks? I am have been completely unable to reproduce the problem so far.

Comment: You really do not want Try Catch blocks swallowing exceptions like that. I still cannot see any problems here. In desperation, it might be worth posting the code for the whole form (and the designer code too - use Pastebin for it so this thread doesn't become huge). I'm frustrated by this now because I just can't see any problems!

Also, how many items are in each list once loaded?

Comment: okay solved it in another way... changed from 3 listboxes to 1 and divided the vallues with '' and use array.split to get the right values. it works fine now. thanks for all the help anyway :D posted my solution under my problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end. Still totally puzzled as to why you were getting an error though - try as I might I couldn't get it to fail!

Comment: yeah really weird... their was no logic to the error.. tried many solutions but it didn't work.. that's why i did it another way.